# Type casting error while parsing json response for int value in java

Tags: java, json, casting

I am parsing below json and want to fetch value of EnterpriseFlag

```
"CardholderDetails": 
{
            "FirstName": "Manoj",
            "LastName": "Pandy",
            "ProfileImageUrl": "https://www.Mark.com/ImageLinkImages/MK0557/Pandey,Manoj_500617996.jpg",
            "BuildingNumber": "MK0557",
            "CardholderInstId": 0,
            "EnterpriseFlag": 6
}
```

below is my code

```
int cardholderInstId = cardholderdetail.get("CardholderInstId");    
System.out.println(cardholderInstId);
```

it shows error Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to int and it shows option to cast to Integer,

```
int cardholderInstId = (Integer) cardholderdetail.get("CardholderInstId");
System.out.println(cardholderInstId);
```

if i cast to Integer and prints it value it shows error. (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at com.jason.example.JASONParser.ReadJSON.main)

Please help !!! Thanks in advance..

Comment: Think about what the error message is telling you.  `cardholderdetail.get("CardholderInstId")` is returning a `Long` and you are trying to narrow that to an `Integer`.  Hint: Use `long` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JSON parser you're using is parsing `CardholderInstId` into a `Long` instead of an `Integer`.

Cast to `Long` then use the `intValue()` method on that object to get it as an int.